# How to send "POST" request with params in Android?

Tags: android, api, post, request

I am crawling data from a website. For that I need to POST to this API
URL : https://api.import.io/store/connector/3b14652e-4785-4402-b1a8-d9363c8e988e/_query?_apikey=

For getting a response, I also need to send some raw data. The data is basically a response Json data retrieved from another POST request. The Api will then perform query over the raw data and send the response.

How do I go about doing this for Android App ?

Here is my HTML code for POST

```
POST /store/connector/3b14652e-4402-b1a8-d9363c8e988e/_login?_apikey=mykey HTTP/1.1 
Host: api.import.io
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7f95c060-0c59-d92b-xxxx-9b9184527208
{
"username": "user",
"password": "pass"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should help you solve your problem or put you on the right tracks:

```
URL url = new URL("your_api_url");

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);

Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
builder.appendQueryParameter("data"  , "json_value");
String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));
writer.write(query);
writer.flush();
writer.close();

int response = conn.getResponseCode();
if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
{
    InputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
    //bis is your json do whatever you want with it
}
conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. But I am still struck. How do I get the response? I know that it is in Json format.

Comment: Sorry didn't know you wanted to get a response, I've updated the answer according to it.

Comment: This should go inside a class with Asynk extended?

Answer (score 0):

Use Volley post library to achieve this

Add this line in dependencies to gradle

`compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.16'`

Write down this helper Volley Request class

```
public class JSONObjectAuthRequest extends JsonObjectRequest
{
    private final Map<String, String> headers;

    public JSONObjectAuthRequest(int method, Map<String, String> headers, String url, JSONObject json, Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        super(method, url, json, listener, errorListener);

        this.headers = headers;
   }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return headers;
    }
 }
```

And use the above Class to pass your request

```
JSONObjectAuthRequest request = new JSONObjectAuthRequest(Request.Method.POST, null, url, postParam, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //  write your logic here
                Log.d(TAG, "Success");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                Log.d(TAG, "Failure");
            }
        });

        RequestManager.getInstance(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

This should help.

Cheers,
sha

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like that :`

```
            try {
                        URL reqURL = new URL(link); //the URL we will send the request to
                        HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) (reqURL.openConnection());
                        request.setDoOutput(true);
                        request.addRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(parameters.length()));
//where parameter is a string written like this : paramKey1=value1&paramKey2=value2
                        request.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //add the content type of the request, most post data is of this type
                        request.setRequestMethod("POST");
                        request.connect();
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(request.getOutputStream());
                        writer.write(parameters);
                        writer.flush();
                        writer.close();
                        int responseCode = request.getResponseCode();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }`
```

And most of all, do not forget to execute these lines into a new thread because you cannot do this in the ui thread. Hope it helps.